# C++ makefile not creating a necessary .o file

Tags: c++, makefile

The following is my makefile for compiling a few basic C++ files into an executable:

```
OBJ= node.o link.o trie.o testtrie.o
OPTS= -g -c -Wall -Werror

testtrie: $(OBJ)
        g++ -o testtrie $(OBJ)

testtrie.o: prog3.cc trie.h trie.cc link.h link.cc node.h node.cc
        g++ $(OPTS) prog3.cc

trie.o: trie.cc trie.h
        g++ $(OPTS) trie.cc

link.o: link.cc link.h
        g++ $(OPTS) link.cc

node.o: node.cc node.h
        g++ $(OPTS) node.cc

clean:
        rm -f *.o *~
```

However, when I run `make`, upon trying to compile prog3.cc, it says:

> g++: testtrie.o: No such file or directory.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it doesn't make testtrie.o...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your executable (*testtrie*) depends on *testtrie.o*.

By default, a compiler (g++ in our case), when compiling a source file (e.g. *src.cc*) if *-o* is not given the output object file will match the source file name, so it will be *src.o*. Your *testtrie.o* target is never generated; instead *prog3.o* is:

```
testtrie.o: prog3.cc trie.h trie.cc link.h link.cc node.h node.cc
    g++ $(OPTS) prog3.cc
```

Modify the command to:

```
    g++ $(OPTS) -o $@ prog3.cc
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `testtrie.o` rule:

```
testtrie.o: prog3.cc trie.h trie.cc link.h link.cc node.h node.cc
    g++ $(OPTS) prog3.cc
```

Does not actually build `testtrie.o`, it builds `prog3.o`.

(It also has several prerequisite source files which it doesn't actually use, unless you're doing some unhealthy things with, e.g., `#include`.)

Answer (score 1):

The rule for the target `testtrie.o` should build a `testtrie.o` file like this:

```
testtrie.o: prog3.cc trie.h trie.cc link.h link.cc node.h node.cc
    g++ $(OPTS) prog3.cc -o testtrie.o
```

You can also add an [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) `$@` to make it recognize the output filename based on the target name:

```
testtrie.o: prog3.cc trie.h trie.cc link.h link.cc node.h node.cc
    g++ $(OPTS) prog3.cc -o $@
```

Both version will have the same effect. Also, **remember to correct the remaining targets in the same way**.